# Can data-role="none" be set in the CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css

I need to add `data-role="none"` to all of my buttons who are currently using a `cssclass="classname"` can I go into the actual CSS file and set the `data-role="none"` or would I need to go into every button on my actual ASP.NET page and apply them hard coded, If i can what would be the line that I place into that file?

Comment: not possible with css but yes with js.

Comment: data-role is an attribute, not a CSS styling property, if you need such a thing then why dont you create a basic button (custom or user control) and then inherit every other button from this button, or just use this special button wherever u need it

Comment: @Era explain? & Usman how would i go about this? just set all my buttons to a 'Inherit="<button with datarole>" it's for a application ... there must be a way to set it to all buttons as it is instead of going through them all 1 by 1 adding more code.

Comment: When creating user control, you can then set the default properties and when using it, you just need to put a referrence in web.config and then use it like for normal buttons u do: <asp:Button ... thus for your user control you will do: <myButton: ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in `CSS` but you can add it using `jQuery`.

If your HTML is like this:

```
<button class="classname">Submit</button>
```

jQuery should be like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.classname").attr("data-role","none");
});
</script>
```

But if your HTML is like this:

```
<input type="button" class="classname" name="btnSub" value="Submit" />
```

jQuery should be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button'].classname").attr("data-role","none");
});
</script>
```

There would be a big difference in the `selector`.

---

If your new to jQuery. Please have a quick look on this [**link**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp) on how to used it.

Comment: I will try this & come back to you Jaun.

Comment: Can you please post here the same HTML of your button? The selector could have been the problem.

Comment: @Kallumasaurus, Juan is correct, we need to see your code to tell you what is wrong. The jQuery code in mine and his answer is correct, so the problem will be in the way _you use it_. Just edit your question and add your ASP.NET / HTML and JS code

Comment: This has helped me a little bit into the guidance of my answer , marked as.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in CSS, but it cand be done easily with jQuery.

```
$( ".classname" ).attr( "data-role", "none" );
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JohnWillemse Me saying "What about jQuery?" instead of "Not in CSS but you can add it using jQuery." doesn't mean it doesn't provide an answer to the question and as you can clearly  notice, most of the answers come with a jQuery solution.

Comment: I was reviewing low-quality posts from a review queue and this was flagged as low quality. My impression was that the answer is not answering the question, but raising another question, which might be an error on my side. Maybe you should edit your post to read something along the lines of: "You can do this easily with jQuery:" and explain why. That will improve the overall quality of both your post and the site, and will help future users facing a similar issue much better.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously attempting to set an HTML attribute with a CSS declaration. This is not possible with CSS.

The CSS style that is applied to an element does not work on attributes. Instead, each HTML element has **separate** set of properties that are independent from attributes and are only affected by the stylesheets. It may be confusing, as many HTML elements have attributes like `width` and `height` and stylesheet properties with the **same name**, but yet they are **different things**. The today's conventions and rules discourage the use of these attributes in favor of the CSS stylesheet.

A good way to achieve your goal is to use JavaScript, or jQuery. There are plenty examples on the web of how to affect attributes of an HTML element. For instance, jQuery has a [convenient way](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to work with **data attributes** (which you also seem to use):

```
jQuery.data(element, "role", "none");
```

There is an easier [alternative approach](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for the same effect as the above

```
$(elementSelector).data("role", "none");
```

The example code will set the attribute `"data-role"` to `"none"`. Notice the lack of `"data-"` in the attribute name with these approaches - jQuery automatically takes care of it.

For your case, the jQuery code would look like this:

```
$(".classname").data("role", "none");
```

assuming you had `class` instead of `cssclass` in mind. If you are using ASP.NET with standard web controls, the ASP.NET `CssClass` attribute is rendered as the HTML `class` attribute, so the above should work for you

Comment: You should write your js code in a place where it will be invoked once the page is rendered. See in [Juan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830619/can-data-role-none-be-set-in-the-css/22830780#22830780) he used `$(document).ready(...)` Another approach would be to put it in a click handler of a button or other control. You should specify these details in your question though.

Answer (score 1):

No, you certainly cannot set any HTML attributes with CSS. CSS cannot in any way change anything in HTML markup or DOM properties corresponding to them. It can only affect rendering of elements (and may mask out the effect of an HTML attribute, but not be changing it).

You should generate the attributes using server-side tools, ASP in your case. It would normally be pointless to use client-side scripting for the purpose, since the main reason for using `data-*` attributes is to provide element-specific data for client-side scripts to process. So a script would basically be informing itself about something that it already knows.

Note that `data-role` is not a particularly good choice for a custom attribute name, since it can be confused with the attribute [`role`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) defined in specifications. There is no specific rule against such a choice of name, though.